# Reading from DATA file handle

Tags: performance, perl

My perl module needs to use a look up table that's about 309,000 lines long.

Currently the part that loads the table into an array looks (roughly) like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# load all the data from below
my @ref_data; 
while (<DATA>) {
    push @ref_data, $_
}
close DATA;

__DATA__
00004f15ed000023f2
00005015fc000623ec
000051160a000b23e7
000052161d001523e2
0000531631002223de
0000541645002e23da
... etc ...
```

My own experiments on show that this `while` loop takes about 0.1 seconds to load the data.  This is about twice as fast as just doing this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# load all the data from below
my @ref_data = <DATA>; 
close DATA;

__DATA__
00004f15ed000023f2
00005015fc000623ec
000051160a000b23e7
000052161d001523e2
0000531631002223de
0000541645002e23da
... etc ...
```

And both of these are much faster than just putting `qw(...)` round all the data lines or editing the source to load the array one item at a time.

I can guess that most of the approx 100 milliseconds is disk time, but is the `while` loop the fastest way to initialize my array, or can we go any faster by using some other Perl construct?

Comment: @Borodin I'll update the question

Comment: Sorry, my arithmetic was wrong - that's 60ms!

Comment: Do you really need this to run faster than 100ms?

Comment: For what it's worth, I replicated your results (perl 5.16, Windows 7). `my @values = <DATA>;` averaged 192ms; the while loop averaged 119ms. Interestingly, `my $values = [<DATA>];` took even longer: 240ms. I thought it might be faster (no need to copy the array), but no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some benchmarking against three methods. I used an external file for reading (instead of `__DATA__`). The file consisted of 3 million lines of the exact data you were using.

The methods are slurping the file, reading the file line-by line, and using `Storable` as Sobrique mentioned above. Each task is run 100 times. Here are the results, which show that once stored using `Storable`, it is by far much faster than the other two (118% faster than by line, and 45% faster than by slurping):

```
           Rate  by_line by_slurp by_store
by_line  1.08/s       --     -33%     -54%
by_slurp 1.62/s      50%       --     -31%
by_store 2.36/s     118%      45%       --
```

Here's the code I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Benchmark qw(cmpthese timethese);
use Storable;

my $file = 'in.txt';

storeit();

cmpthese(100, {
    'by_line' => \&by_line,
    'by_slurp' => \&by_slurp,
    'by_store' => \&by_store,
});

sub by_line {

    open my $fh, '<', $file
      or die "Can't open $file: $!";

    my @ref_data;

    for my $line (<$fh>){
        push @ref_data, $line;
    }
}

sub by_slurp {

    open my $fh, '<', $file
      or die "Can't open $file: $!";

    my @ref_data = <$fh>;
}  

sub storeit {
    open my $fh, '<', $file
      or die "Can't open $file: $!";

    my @ref_data = <$fh>;
    close $fh;

    store \@ref_data, 'store.dat';
}

sub by_store{

    my @ref_data = retrieve('store.dat');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`DATA` is a special file handle that's embedded into your script. It isn't much different from reading in data from a file normally. I would suggest though that using inlined data for 300k lines is probably not an ideal way of approaching it.

Have you had a look at `Storable`? You might find that you can `store` and `retrieve` your data structure - you'll probably need to keep your file for initial loading.

Alternatively - do you actually need all your reference data held in memory? It's fast to do direct memory access, but if you're not doing sequential key processing, you may find database style lookup on demand is better still?

Failing that - you might also find that having a separate 'loader' thread that processes your file asynchronously might be an option too, as whilst it will still take time to load into memory, your program can just carry on whilst the data is being loaded.

But pretty fundamentally - you're reading a large chunk of data serially from disk. It will always be limited by the speed of the disk. Faster disk means faster load.  The workarounds for this are things that move from disk to memory (like a database).